# c++ Script that finds questions in string

Tags: c++, string, vector, find

I am new at coding , been coding for about a week and i am trying to do a script that finds the "?" and the "." in the script , then outputs their position in the script and i use those value to print the question to a text file.

Except it does not really work.

If you put the value in like this, it works.

```
myfile << test.substr( 18, 20 )
```

But like this it does not work it just print the whole script from the value of dot[0] until the end of the script.

```
myfile << test.substr( dot[0], interrogation[0] )
```

The way that i use to find the "?" position in the string is also not very accurate.

Where there is the .

```
    if(x > 0){
```

I had a while loop but i replaced it for debugging reasons .
This is the whole code.
If you can help me i appreciate it.
Thanks.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main (){



std::vector< int > interrogation ;
std::vector< int > dot;



string look = "?";
string look_again = ".";


string test = "ver. o que e isto? nao sei. ola? adeus. fghfghfhfghf";



string::size_type pos = test.find(look);
string::size_type sop = test.find(look_again);
string::size_type exc = test.find(look_again_again);


while (pos != std::string::npos)
{



int a = pos ;
int b = sop;



   cout << " . found at : " << sop << std::endl;
   cout << " ? found at : " << pos << std::endl;

interrogation.push_back(a);
dot.push_back(b);


string fragment = test.substr (0 , pos );    // works
//cout << fragment << endl ;

string fragment2 = test.substr (0 , sop );    // works
//cout << fragment2 << endl ;


  pos = test.find(look, pos + 1);
  sop = test.find(look_again, sop + 1);

}





int x = 1;

if(x > 0){





int a = 1;

int q = dot[a];
int w = interrogation[a];
// to save text


// to save text
string save = "saved_question.txt" ;
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open (save.c_str(), ios::app);
myfile << test.substr( 18, 20 ) + "\n"  ;
myfile.close();


cout << "Question saved in text file" << endl;




}



}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `string::find_first_of` ?

Comment: I am gonna try it , but that does not solve the problem of outputin to the text file

Comment: It works thanks man  , you are the best

Answer (score 0):

The code is not finished yet but i got it working with help.
Thanks

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main (){



std::vector< int > interrogation ;
std::vector< int > dot;
//std::vector< int > exclamation;



string look = "?";
string look_again = ".";
string look_again_again = "!";

string test = " ver.o que e isto? nao sei. ola? adeus.";



string::size_type pos = test.find(look);
string::size_type sop = test.find(look_again);



while (pos != std::string::npos)
{



int a = pos ;
int b = sop;



   cout << " . found at : " << sop << std::endl;
   cout << " ? found at : " << pos << std::endl;
  // cout << " ! found at : " << exc << std::endl;

interrogation.push_back(a);
dot.push_back(b);
//exclamation.push_back(c);

string fragment = test.substr (0 , pos  );    // works
//cout << fragment << endl ;

string fragment2 = test.substr (0 , sop) ;    // works
//cout << fragment2 << endl ;



string fragment3 = test.substr (dot.back() + 1,  interrogation.back() -       dot.back());    // works
cout << fragment3 << endl ;




  pos = test.find(look, pos + 1);
  sop = test.find(look_again, sop + 1);





}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
void function(string str) {
  string sentence = "";
  for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if(str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '!')
          sentence = ""; // the sentence is not a question so clear the sentence
      else if(str[i] == '?') {
          sentence.push_back(str[i]);
          cout << sentence << endl; // output the question - just replace cout with your ofstream
      }
      else
          sentence.push_back(str[i]);
  }
}
```

I think I've seen this question before though..